# Комментарии к отзывам

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Как организовать комментарии к отзывам?

Хочу понять, как правильно.
У меня создана таблица (`feed`) в *бд*  для хранения отзыва:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->text('comment');
$table->string('name');
$table->date('u_start');
$table->date('u_end');
$table->timestamps();
```

Для хранения комментариев к отзыву необходимо создать новую таблицу типа `comment(id ,id_feed, name, comment, timestamp)`  и добавить в имеющуюся значение `bool('has_comment');`, или удобнее все хранить в одной таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Коментарий это отдельная сущность, поэтому вам конечно лучше создать новую модель и таблицу в БД. Типа такой
`comment( id , feed_id, title , text , timestamp )`
Поле has_comment добавлять не нужно, так как можно сделать подзапрос и если результат не пустой то коментарии есть.